# Is mutable object wrapped inside an immutable object safe?

Tags: java, immutability

If I have a data structure which looks like this:

```
ImmutableObj<MutableMap<String,Integer>> myObj;
```

Is the above enough to ensure immunity? Or do I have to make `MutableMap` immutable as well?

Comment: Safe for what? The values in the mutable map might change; does your design depend on that not happening?

Comment: No, that is ofcourse not enough to make the whole thing immutable. The map inside the object must also be immutable.

Comment: In fact, I would go so far as to say that it's not wrapped in an immutable object. The"outer" object is mutable because its state (including the "inner" object) can change.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thats a very good question. Lets say I want to keep a dictionary of how many times a word comes up in a book (stored in MutableMap). Am I correct to say that this implementation can cause problem?

Comment: @Jesper thanks for your comment. In that case, is there any usefulness for this kind of structure?

Comment: @xcoder Your current approach is probably fine if your application is single threaded. For multithreaded use, I'd prefer a  `ImmutableObj<MutableMap<String,AtomicInteger>> myObj;` If it really needs to be immutable, then you can't have a counter.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Even then, you'd need an atomic "put if not already present" method on the MutableMap (which HashMap doesn't have, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

It's safe when you don't expose link to original mutable object like this (example with lists, same method for map is presents in Collections class):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar"); 
List<String> immutableStrings = Collections.unmodifiableList(strings);
```

because you may have to modify immutableStrings list through strings list.
Better approach is to don't have links to mutable list at all like:

```
List<String> immutableStrings = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar"));
```

Here we don't have link to inner mutable list with foo and bar, and not able to modify immutableStrings list.

It's synthetic example, from conversation under your question i understand that you may want something like this:

```
public Map<String, Integer> wordFruquencyIn(String book, String word) {
    //do calculation here

    Map<String, Integer> result = //result
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result); // return unmodifiable map 
}
```

Better to create custom class that represents result of calculation instead of map, because contracts of Map, List, etc... unclear in way you don't know if they mutable or not (lack of method isMutable() and lack of design in early java versions in general (see LSP principle in this case)). After refactor you code may be like that:

```
public Statistics wordFruquencyIn(String book, String word) {
    //do calculation here

    Map<String, Integer> result = //result
    return new StatisticsImpl(result);
}

public interface Statistics {  

    public String word() {} 

    public int times() {}

}
```

You may create any implementation of Statistics interface that fulfill contract of this interface and have map inside or any mutable data, only one way to communicate with this class is ask about `word()` that returns already immutable string or `times()` that returns a primitive.